# Update via array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a trouble in update. When I submit the form, the parameter gives me an Hash of values like `{"1"=>"1", "4"=>"1"}`. I want only the values to be updated. So, I have separated the Keys and Values `keys, values = @period.map { |k,v| [k.to_i, v.to_i] }.transpose` where `@period = {"1"=>"1", "4"=>"1"}`. where I get the values like `[1,4]`. So, How can I update it via this array. when I use update_attributes only the last value(4). How can I update the fields via array. I am new to rails , so be calm.

Comment: How are you using `update_attributes`? Post that code.

Comment: In the update action I has `Period.where(subject_id: :subject_id).update_all(subject_id: values)`. I get no errors while running but the problem is,  the values is not changing . In the log file I get 
`SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE periods SET periods.subject_id = NULL WHERE periods.subject_id = NULL`

Comment: Can you post the entire controller method, some sample data from your params, and what you would like to happen if everything worked okay?

Comment: Hi @DanLaffan, I have posted the full code in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669719/update-via-hash-or-array) . Please look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to this solution doesn't follow the Rails convention, which is why you are finding it difficult.  Doing things the Rails way will make your life much easier.

**TLDR**: You should use nested attributes and build your form around the parent object, @institution.  See this part of the Rails Guides on how to implement this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

**In more detail...**

You appear to have a Period model, a Subject model, and an Institution model.  Periods appear to belong to Subjects and probably belong to the Institution as well.  Correct me if I am wrong.

You appear to be breaking with Rails conventions in the following ways:

1. You are using a show method and view when you should be using an edit method and view.
2. You are using a form_tag when you could use a form_for.
3. You are calling a model directly from your view.
4. You are not using nested attributes in processing multiple child records of a parent.

In summary, you should change your approach to do the following:

1. Make the institutions_controller#update method responsible for updating your periods data in bulk.
2. Add this to your Institution model:

   ```
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :periods
   ```
3. In your institutions_controller, add the params for periods into the institution's params, for example:

   ```
   params.require(:institution).permit(
       :name,
       # whatever else is there now...
       periods_attributes: [
           :id,
           :subject_id,
           :institution_id
      ]
   )
   ```
4. Update your institutions/_form to look something like this:

   ```
   <%= form_for @institution do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
     <%= fields_for :periods do |p| %>
       <%= p.hidden_field :institution_id %>
       <%= p.collection_select :subject_id, @subjects, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
     <% end %>
     <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
   ```

   See how much more elegant it is?  Every attribute is correctly named, and there is no need to guess at what the keys and values mean when you inspect the incoming parameters on submission.
5. Update your institutions_controller#edit method to do something like this:

   ```
   def edit
     @institution = Institution.includes(:periods).find(params[:id])
     @subjects = @institution.subjects.all # assumes subjects belong to institution
   end
   ```
6. Your institutions_controller#update may not need any update, and should look something like this:

   ```
   def update
     @institution = Institution.find(params[:id])
     if @institution.update_attributes(institution_params)
       flash[:success] = "Saved!"
       redirect_to @institution # or wherever you want to go
     else
       @subjects = @institution.subjects.all
       render :edit
     end
   end
   ```

Try this out. HTH