# update via Hash or Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hash

I want to update the `subject_id` field in **Period Model** .Where the period loop will be inside the Form. SO, when I submit the Form the passing Parameter is coming as an hash, where **Key is the `Period.id` and the Value is `subject_id`**. So, How can I update it.

In my **Show.html.erb** I has

```js
<%= form_tag update_institutes_path, method: : put do %>
  <% @period.each do |cc | %>
    <%= cc.subject.name %>
    <%= collection_select('id', cc.id, Subject.all, : id, : name, selected: cc.id, prompt: true) %>
    <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

The **SHow action** I has

```js
def show
  @period = Period.all
end
```

In the **Update action** I have

```js
def update
  @period = params[:id]
  keys, values = @period.map { |k,v| [k.to_i, v.to_i] }.transpose
  values.each { |f| Period.all.update_all(:subject_id => f) }
end
```

where `@period = params[:id]` give a parameter like

```
  #Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8SNaUIQ6ZwjYOqBX07QYyVJsbuvYTL2TotSqIg0yj98nYXq5XqJ5XRHqlCvl1aw0lLg9vowyDOl3Hhm+hYDaOA==", "id"=>{"1"=>"3", "4"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Save changes"}
```

1. where 1 and 4 in the hash is period_id
2. 3 and 2 in the hash is subject_id.

Then I converted the hash to keys and values

1. where keys is period_id
2. values is subject_id.

Then I looped the values and update the Period.

It is updating, but the **Problem is only the last value 2 is updated, where every subject_id becomes 2, I don't no what happens to 3(the first value), only the last value is updated.** I am just banging my head to solve this problem for two days. I am new to rails, Please be kind. Thanks for the answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a hash where the keys are `period_id` and the values are `subject_id`. Assuming your hash name is `period_and_subjects`, you want to do this:

```
Period.update(period_and_subjects.keys, period_and_subject.values)
```

So, if your `period_and_subjects` hash looks like `{1 => 2, 4 => 5}`, it would update the period with id 1 with the subject with id 2 and the period with id 4 with the subject with id 5.

Look at the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) for `update`.